# Browsers refuse to connect to websites without url scheme provided

Tags: apache, ubuntu, url, webserver

I recently updated my webserver to Ubuntu 16.04 and after the update, I'm getting issues with browsers refusing to connect when the url doesn't include https://

I made sure to check ufw to verify 'Apache Full' was allowed and it was, not sure what to check from here. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone else online here has solved the same problem with the same version of Ubuntu, you will probably have to debug this. I cannot debug it for you because I am not at your keyboard. However, I can get you started.

From a machine other than the web server, try the command

```
openssl s_client -connect HOSTNAME:80
```

Replace HOSTNAME with the web server's hostname. If it complains, "Connection refused," then your new web server is no longer serving HTTP. On the other hand, if OpenSSL connects, then your new web server is at least trying to serve HTTP. (Note that OpenSSL, if called as above, won't do anything useful when it connects. It should just drop the connection after a few seconds, but the point is that is connects.)

If, for purpose of comparison, you wish to see what a good HTTP connection looks like, then try

```
openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:80
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! The issue was I had Listen 8080, instead of Listen 80 in ports.conf. Pretty sure I had some port forwarding setup originally when I setup the server (5+ years ago) that I forgot to account for. Thanks again.

Comment: Righto. If the answer is useful, you can *accept* it by checking the green mark left of the answer.